# TeXnicCenter - hotkeys for user-defined command or AutoHotkey without overwriting marked content?

Tags: texniccenter

defined commands which I want to use in fast way. I tried to make a short  hotkey, not the long default one for inserting own text blocks, but I did not find an option for that. Then I thought I would use `AutoHotkey`, but
normally in TeXnicCenter when you select some text and use a command like `\textit{}`the text wont be overwritten. If I use `Autohotkey` for my customized command, I select my text and it will be overwritten.

Is there a solution I did not see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is possible at least for the F-keys. The following script copies the selected text, inserts `\command{}`, moves the cursor left and inserts the text again.

```
F4::
Send ^c
Send \command{{}{}}{LEFT}
Send ^v
Return
```

Comment: why only F-keys?

Comment: Well, `F`-keys do not mess with the text you entered, for combinations like `Alt`+<Key> it should probably work as well. But as soon as any keys are printed out, you do not have the original chars to copy to the clipboard.

Comment: Just to go sure: This is an Autohotkey script? Please add a short info.

Comment: Yes, this is `Autohotkey`.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this question was asked but I had the same problem and solved it with an AutoIt script:

## include

```
$dll = DllOpen("user32.dll")
While 1   
   if _IsPressed("05") then 
      WinActivate("XXX")
      Send("!im2")
   EndIf 
   if _IsPressed("04") then 
      WinActivate("XXX")
      Send("!im1")
   EndIf
   Sleep(100)
WEnd
DllClose($dll)

Exit
```

Instead of "XXX" you type just the beginning of the window's name of TeXnicCenter (usually the project's name).

The parameter of the _IsPressed-function defines the hotkey (04 for middle mouse button, 05 for X1 mouse button).

"!im2" means it presses ALT+i to get into the insert menu, then m and 2